# Why did base64 win against uuencode?

Tags: history, unix, file-format

From the the two methods of encoding 8-bit data as human-readable ASCII, for a time, uuencode format was more popular. USENET 'binaries' groups were filled with uuencoded posts with whatever goodies were shared. The format was quite robust, insensitive to line breaks (if your mail program reflowed the text, for uuencode you could still decode the file) and the uuencode/uudecode programs were quite user-friendly.

Base64 was not nearly so well liked. Some people would post base64-encoded binaries, arousing mild ire from these, who didn't have decoders. It was sensitive to formatting and white spaces. I'm not entirely sure, but I think it generated a little bigger output too.

Then I was off-the-loop for a time, and when I came back to the Unix and Linux world, uuencode was dead, and wherever 7-bit was still needed, Base64 ruled, and rules to this day.

What happened? What events led to base64 winning the format war?

Comment: uuencode IIRC had leading/trailing whitespace as being meaningful, which could cause issues AFAIK.

Comment: I remember the time when [btoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) was all the rage.

Comment: uuencode was a *de-facto standard* that never made it into any RFC. Base64 was a *real standard* that made it into the earliest MIME RFCs and ended up in a dedicated (RFC3548, RFC3648) one.

Comment: @tofro somehow I think if the MIME designers had wanted UUencode, they’d have added it to the RFC ;-).

Comment: Actually, reflowed uuencode, although theoretically recoverable, was not handled well by the tools. Conversely, the standard Base64 decoding algorithm doesn't care about spaces or line breaks at all.

Comment: Base64 is not sensitive to whitespace formatting at all as whitespace is specified to have a very specific meaning in base64: it means ignore this byte and read the next byte.

Comment: One problem of all that retro- stuff... one forgets. Apparently it was b64 that was immune to reflow. I get it.

Comment: Is this question on topic?  There are lots of "retro" technologies but do they all belong here?  This seems like more of a programmers question.  Amiga IFF format seems on-topic.  But b64?  I'm not saying it doesn't belong at all...just seems a little out of place.  But with over 30+ upvotes, I could be wrong.

Comment: @cbmeeks: this is about a format war, that took place around 2000. I don't think the fact the victor of this war (created in 1993) survives to this day should be a problem - in particular, demise of the competitor is the primary focus here.

Comment: @SF fair enough.

Comment: Re, "...as human-readable ASCII..." I never found either one of them to be particularly "human readable." The real point was to be able to pass binary data through channels (e.g., email) that were designed around plain-text documents.

Comment: The fact that base64 does not use `<` or `>` also makes it easier to include base64 content in HTML/XML documents.

Comment: Although this question mentions the Unix/Linux world, those formats were used much more widely — which may have some bearing on the answer.  (Other machines connecting to the Internet and transferring files included Macs, Ataris, Amigas, Archimedes, and I'm sure I recall IBM making something…)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I’m not sure about specific events, but I think the main reason Base64 “won” is that it’s one of the binary encodings supported by [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), and MIME took over.

So perhaps the question then becomes two-fold:

- Why did MIME pick Base64 over uuencode? Possibly because Base64 is actually [more resilient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding#Relation_to_Xxencode.2C_Base64.2C_and_Ascii85) than uuencode: it only uses alphanumeric characters plus two other characters to encode content (`+` and `/` in MIME), and one character for padding (`=`).
- Why did MIME become the dominant mail/news content wrapper? I guess it boils down to convenience, especially once most MUAs and news agents supported it (ah, the days of `slrn` and Forte Agent…).

Comment: I'm actually curious why the "URL-safe" version isn't just *the* version, or at least why `/` was chosen instead of a safer non-path character.

Comment: @Nick MIME was invented in 1990 or 1991, and codified in 1992; URLs were invented in 1992 and codified in 1994. So URL-safety didn’t exist when MIME was invented. (That doesn’t answer the non-path aspect of course since file system paths already used `/`.)

Comment: I think more importantly, base64 is "more stream-oriented" than uuencode, which is more "line/record oriented".

Comment: @Vatine that’s a good point, with uuencode’s length prefix bytes.

Answer (score 37):

The problem with uuencode is that the format was *not* robust in the face of some of the really crufty mail software and gateways into and out of proprietary non-SMTP and non-ASCII mail systems of the day. Just to liven things up further, there were multiple EBCDIC variants which had different code points for some ASCII characters used by uuencode, opening up another route for data corruption. For example, the character `$` has code point 74 in [code page 285](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_285) used in the UK, but code point 91 in [code page 037](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037) used in the USA.

This corruption would have been one of the driving forces behind the design of MIME, and its character set would have been carefully chosen to minimise problems with such gateways.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why the variation between character assignments in various EBCDIC code pages is more of a problem for uuencode than for base64?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Adding up the letters a-z and A-Z, along with the digits 0-9, yields 62 characters.  Thus, base64 only requires two more characters to get to 64, and finding two characters that behave consistently on all systems isn't too hard.

Comment: Sure, @supercat, but both uuencode and base64 are predicated on the ASCII mappings for the characters used (and uuencode uses only a few more distinct characters than does base64).  It follows that if a uuencoded or base64 object is transcoded to the recipient's local encoding in transit, then that has to be accommodated at the receiver either way.  In particular, EBCDIC maps *all* letters and digits differently than ASCII does.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, UUEncode uses the upper-case letters, the numbers, and a wide range of punctuation.  Base64 uses the upper- and lower-case letters, the numbers, and two punctuation characters.  Looking at a selection of EBCDIC Latin-1 code pages, the letters and numbers have consistent code points, but the punctuation code points vary wildly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are misunderstanding the problem.  I uuencode a binary into ASCII text containing a dollar sign.  I send that to some gateway that understands it is getting ASCII and converts to EBDIC.  The gateway then forwards to another EBCDIC machine that fails to handle the code-page conversion (so the dollar has been mangled to something else).  Finally the second EBCDIC machine converts back to ASCII and sends the text to you.  You try to uudecode and it all goes horribly wrong.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinBonner, that is indeed the clarification I was asking for.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Base64 is not "predicated on the ASCII mappings", except vacuously in the fact that the characters exist at all (vs uuencode which uses the low six bits of a set of 64 consecutive ASCII characters), and the earliest formal description of, RFC 2045, does explicitly mention EBCDIC. And, in fact, "This subset has the important property that it is represented identically in all versions of ISO 646, including US-ASCII, and all characters in the subset are also represented identically in all versions of EBCDIC. "

Comment: Note that there was a variant of uuencode (xxencode) which used only the alphanumeric characters and plus and minus, to avoid problems with character set translation.

Answer (score 16):

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is slightly more compact as it does not use a character indicating line length at the beginning of each line:

```
% dd bs=1k count=1024 < /dev/urandom | uuencode /dev/stdout | wc -с
1444736
% dd bs=1k count=1024 < /dev/urandom | uuencode -m /dev/stdout | wc -c
1421440
```

Overall, Base64 is about 1.5% better.

Comment: this is not an answer. this is a comment

Comment: To me this is exactly the answer that clarifies why base64 is used and not uuencode.

Comment: For reference this `uuencode` seems to come from the sharutils package (shell archive utils) and its `-m` switch indeed switches to base64 mode.

Answer (score 13):

Some of the reasons base64 was disliked was because uuencode stored the original file name and file mode of the encoded data.  Also, uuencode had been around longer and was more established, which meant that many people had a uudecode program available but they did not have a base64 decoder.  Keep in mind at that time, many people were using systems that did not have a C compiler (the C compiler was often sold as an expensive add-on if it was available at all, and this was before GCC was widely available) so acquiring and compiling their own base64 decoder was a significant effort.

But in certain contexts you didn't need a file name or mode (e.g. inline encoding of the body of an email message), and uuencoded data was particularly vulnerable to corruption because at that time it was not uncommon for a mail gateway somewhere along the line to insert an unwanted newline somewhere within
your message, or for character set translation to corrupt something.  The extra newlines were usually easy to fix, and the uuencode format made it easy to see where they had occurred, but corruption due to character set translation was much harder to fix (sometimes impossible without trial-and-error testing).  Base64 encoding solved these problems and was therefore a better choice for use within the MIME email encoding standard.

The decline in popularity of terminal-mode access compared to GUI access is what really killed uuencode.  Users who were using graphical email clients on a PC or on a Workstation or X Terminal, found base64-encoded MIME attachments more convenient than uuencoding, and web browsers allowed you to download files without needing any encoding at all (shifting the common method of binary file transfer away from mail and news, towards the use of FTP and HTTP instead).  Uuencoding is still an easy way to send a file when both the sender and receiver are using text-only terminals and can't use FTP, but today this is almost never the case.

Comment: I don't agree with the comment about C compilers. I can remember when Sun announced that Solaris would no longer come with a C compiler and whilst there was much outrage, in practice we shrugged our shoulders and installed gcc. I think the issue is more likely that most people didn't want to have to write a base64 decoder. Whilst it's not hard, getting it right is not completely trivial and probably out of reach for non programmers.

Comment: uuencode was in common use when Solaris did not yet exist, it was still SunOS.  The systems that did not come with bundled C compilers were running things like System III / System V / Xenix.  possibly also vendor-specific versions like AIX / HP-UX but I'm not sure.  also at that time it was difficult to install gcc if you didn't have a C compiler already, because you needed an existing C compiler to compile gcc to start with.  then step two would be to use gcc to recompile itself, and step three would be to repeat and confirm you got identical binaries.

Comment: My recollection is that all of those versions of Unix you list had C compilers bundled. I may be misremembering, but I worked with System V, Xenix, AIX and HP-UX in ancient days and don't remember us having to buy the C compiler.

Comment: @KenGober There was a tarball of a Solaris gcc available (GNU mirrors perhaps) for the exact purpose of providing the first compiler to bootstrap a new version of gcc.

Answer (score 2):

I can't definitively say whether it is cause or effect so am somewhat chancing my arm by promoting it to an answer but: the only way of forming a data URL (i.e. one that has the data directly within it†) is as base64.

Since all moderately substantial application environments supports URLs, even if they don't explicitly support base64 encoding and decoding then they at least support decoding just by forming the data URL. So it's just really easy for developers to support.

Therefore I think base64's usage in URLs may have contributed to its ascension, in the same way that its use in the IBM PC helped the x86 — it's not where the thing came from or why it was designed, but it led to a substantial propagation.

† e.g. [this tiny document icon](http://data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwAOAMQfAP////7+/vj4+Hh4eHd3d/v7+/Dw8HV1dfLy8ubm5vX19e3t7fr6+nl5edra2nZ2dnx8fMHBwYODg/b29np6eujo6JGRkeHh4eTk5LCwsN3d3dfX13Jycp2dnevr6////yH5BAEAAB8ALAAAAAALAA4AAAVq4NFw1DNAX/o9imAsBtKpxKRd1+YEWUoIiUoiEWEAApIDMLGoRCyWiKThenkwDgeGMiggDLEXQkDoThCKNLpQDgjeAsY7MHgECgx8YR8oHwNHfwADBACGh4EDA4iGAYAEBAcQIg0DkgcEIQA7) that I cribbed from [this site](http://dataurl.net/#about), which doesn't identify a remote resource but itself contains a local resource. You might need to copy and paste it into your browser bar if yours is anything like mine, as trying to follow it like a link from here inevitably leads to the error that it's not a functioning link. Which is the point.

Comment: I'd say Base64 was already en vogue (for e-mail) when nobody even knew what an URL was supposed to be...

Comment: The relevant RFC is from 1998 — https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397 — when do we think uuencode lost dominance?

Comment: Base64 encoding is already defined (even if the name wasn't established yet) in RFC1421 from 1993

Comment: I think I've partly misread you, for which I apologise. I read it as being that base64 had ascended before being incorporated into URLs. Which is accidentally a corollary of your point, but I'd just plain misread. You're just saying: its ascension into URLs is consequence, not cause. Which is unarguable if you're dating it to pre-1998.

Comment: I don't think the date of the RFC is as important as widespread support.

Comment: You've got "cause" and "effect" backwards here.  Base64 (RFC 1421) pre-dates URLs (RFC 1738) by almost two years, `data:` URIs (RFC 2397) by five and a half years, and widespread use of `data:` URIs by a decade or more.

Comment: @Mark I'm fully aware of the sequence of events; my suggestion was that by selecting base64 from the competing options for `data:` URLs, the IETF gave it a substantial boost. Like saying that x86 is prevalent because it was used in the IBM PC, even though it predates the IBM PC and the market's winnowing down to the IBM PC.

Comment: @Mark answer edited, as I still think your comment is incorrect and grossly misleading.

Comment: The theory is intriguing, but I doubt `data:` URLs were much of a factor, if only because it took a long time for them to be supported in the dominant browsers ([Internet Explorer 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx) was the first IE version to support them). They weren’t widely used until relatively recently. (I don’t know if they’re really widely used now in fact.)

Comment: The reason your icon link is broken is that you have a stray `http:` (and `//`) preceding it, so it's being parsed as a HTTP URL.  (OTOH, if you fix that, Stack Exchange doesn't even recognise it as an URL at all!)

Answer (score -4):

This also may have a history with multi-byte vs. unicode character.  Multi-byte was a stop-gap support for unicode a while back when uuencode was invented.  Supporting multi-byte is not really needed unless you have some really old backups.

Comment: "..unless you have some really old backups" - or unless you use Java. But who sane would program in Java anyway? Though, technically speaking, surrogates are not only multibyte, but multi-*word*. And, even more technically speaking, UTF-8 is in fact multibyte...  This does not answer the question, though.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík There are plenty of good reasons to program in Java (and many not to) - saneness is not relevant there.   It is very good if you need to build cathedrals that need to stand for "centuries", but not if you just need shelter for the night.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  From what I've seen (admittedly, just a tiny fraction of the wonderful of programming, but over almost 40 years) is that while COBOL has been used to build cathedrals that will stand for centuries (though I've never programmed a line of COBOL myself, ever), Java, by and large, will not last that long. Java, the language, will be around a long time, but I can't see it producing the robust "forever" programs.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Let's have this discussion again in 20 years.